# SQL Find duplicates and Update table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Im trying to update a table with a Duplicate find query, my table is made of 60k+ records and doing this over excel is kinda complicated, My table looks like this

Serial_NO 
       .......Determine Duplicate

1
       .......................Good Record

2
      .......................Good Record

3
      .......................Good Record

1
      .......................Duplicate

The idea of this in to only update the last or more recent duplicate entry in the table by checking the entire "Serial_NO" column and them add the 'Good Record' or 'Duplicate' in column "Determine duplicate".

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Do you have an identity column or is it just the index that lets you know the "Second" record is actually second.

Comment: Are those the only two columns on the table? There is no unique ID field? There should be a PK so that at least something is unique.

Comment: is just the index that let me know that the second is duplicate

Comment: the table has multiple columns on it ID field is part of the table

Comment: Ihis question is probably a duplicate ;-)

Comment: Are you looking for a select query with "Determine Duplicate" as an output column? Or is that an actual field on your table, and you want it to physically hold those values?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia is an actual column on my table and I want to hold the values

Comment: There is no DBMS named "SQL 2008". I assume you mean SQL **Server** 2008

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there is an "id" field on the table, as indicated in your comments:

```
update tbl x
set x.[Determine Duplicate] = 'Good Record'
where x.id = (select min(y.id) from tbl y where y.[Serial_NO] = x.[Serial_NO]);

update tbl x
set x.[Determine Duplicate] = 'Duplicate'
where x.id > (select min(y.id) from tbl y where y.[Serial_NO] = x.[Serial_NO]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is with ROW_NUMBER:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Serial_NO ORDER BY Serial_NO) AS seq
        ,DetermineDuplicate
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    )
UPDATE t
SET DetermineDuplicate = CASE WHEN seq = 1 THEN 'Good Record' ELSE 'Duplicate' END;
```

Answer (score 0):

After considering given comments, I think following answer will suits for your requirement.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET tbl.[Determine Duplicate] = tb.[Determine Duplicate]
FROM tb_src tbl
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT t1.[Serial_NO],
         COALESCE(t2.isduplicate,'Good Record') AS [Determine Duplicate]
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.[Serial_NO]
    FROM tb_src t
  ) t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_src t2
  ON t1.[sno] = t2.sno AND t2.isduplicate = 'Duplicate'
) tb
ON tb.[Serial_NO] = tbl.[Serial_NO]
```

Using above, you can go with a single query.

Please note : `tb_src` is the table you provide.